# Load Google Maps on a View Controller by pressing a button in another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a project where I have implemented a facebook style side scroll menu. What I am trying to accomplish is to load some extra layers on the Google Map underneath by pressing a button on the side menu to call a method, using GMSTileURLConstructor in  the map view controller, however regardless of the approach (tried segue and target action) the block code does not get executed. If I add a button on the map ViewController it works fine.

**Update**
The issue seems to be that even though the method gets called from the SideViewController(slider) the GMSTileURLConstructor does not get x, y and z values in the block and is not executed.

Presumably because the MapView cannot calculate the bounds of the screen since it is partially covered by the slider ??? When tested with :

```
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds= [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithRegion:_mapView.projection.visibleRegion];
 NSLog(@" x:%f, y:%f", bounds.northEast.latitude, bounds.southWest.latitude);
```

Always returns 0.000000 and 0.00000000

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationWithName:@"somename" object:self];` when someone presses a button on the side menu.

Then in the map view controller, listen for the notifications: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleSomenameNotification:) name:@"somename" object:nil];`

And then you can load extra layers in the `handleSomenameNotification:` method. Also, remember to remove yourself as an observer of that notification when you are finished with that view controller.